# Listener still active after component destruction

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm facing an issue with Angular lifecycle hooks, as the OnDestroy event is fired and my component still seem to have its listeners active.

I have a list of projects and a pie chart for each of them, which triggers a popover when hovering them. This popover is a custom component made from Angular Material stuff, but it follows the behavior of similar components (like mat-menu). It has an onOpen listener that triggers when the popover is opened.

The issue here is that the hovering still works after the component and its parent are supposed to be destroyed, which happens every time my list of projects is reloaded.

Here is a simplified version of my implementation:

```js
// Table component
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ChangeDetectorRef, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { select, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Project } from '@models';
import { projectsSelectors } from '@store/track';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-projects-table',
 templateUrl: './projects-table.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./projects-table.component.scss'],
 changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class ProjectsTableComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 projects$: Observable<Array<Project>>;
 projects: Array<Project>;
 subs = new Subscription();

 constructor(
  private store: Store<any>,
  private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
 ) {}

 ngOnInit() {
  this.projects$ = this.store.select(projectsSelectors.all);
 
  this.subs = this.projects$.subscribe((projects) => {
   this.projects = projects;
   this.cd.detectChanges();
  });

 }

 trackByFn(index, item) {
  return item.id;
 }

 ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subs.unsubscribe();
 }

}

// Pie component

import {
 ChangeDetectionStrategy,
 Component,
 Input,
 ViewChild,
 OnDestroy,
 OnInit,
} from '@angular/core';
import { PopoverPanel } from '@ng-components';
import {
 Project,
} from '@models';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-pie',
 templateUrl: './app-pie.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app-pie.component.scss'],
 changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class PieComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 @Input() project: Project;
 @ViewChild('piePopover')
 budgetCompletionPopover: PopoverPanel;

 ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Init budget progress pie', this.budgetCompletionPopover);
 }

 ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log('Destroy pie');
 }
}


// Pie popover component

import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PopoverPanelComponent } from '@ng-components';
import { Project } from '@/models';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-pie-popover',
 templateUrl: './pie-popover.component.html',
})
export class PiePopoverComponent extends PopoverPanelComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 @Input() project: IProject;
 @Output() close = new EventEmitter<void>();
 @Output() open = new EventEmitter<void>();

 constructor() {
  super();
  this.alignment = 'top';
  this.position = 'before';
  this.targetOffsetX = -84;
  this.triggerEvent = 'hover';
  this.overlapTrigger = true;
 }

 ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Init pie popover');
 }

 onOpen() {
    console.log('Opened pie popover', this.project.id);
 }

 ngOnDestroy() {
     console.log('Destroy and close pie popover', this.project.id);
  this.close.emit();
 }
}
```

```html
<!-- Pie Table Component -->

<table class="table">
 <app-projects-table-header class="table-head">
  <app-projects-table-filter></app-projects-table-filter>
 </app-projects-table-header>
 <tbody class="table-body">
    <tr *ngFor="let project of projects; trackBy: trackByFn">
      <app-pie [project]="project"></app-pie>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Pie Component -->

<div class="container" [popoverTriggerFor]="piePopover">
 <ng-container>
    <!-- Project information displayed here -->
 </ng-container>
 <app-pie-chart
  class="graph-pie"
  [size]="55"
  [strokeWidth]="4"
  [progress]="completionRatio"
  [displayValue]="100 * completionRatio"
 >
 </app-pie-chart>
</div>

<app-pie-popover
 #piePopover
 [project]="project"
></app-pie-popover>
```

And the console output when I keep hovering the pie as projects are reloading:

- Init pie
- Init pie popover

Hovering the pie chart

- Opened pie popover 204

Triggering reload and getting back to hovering the pie chart

- Destroy and close pie popover 204
- Destroy pie
- Opened pie popover 204

I would want the popover component to be fully destroyed when it should be to avoid display issues.
Any clue on this is welcome, thanks !

Comment: Are you building your project with AOT?

Comment: No, it is not activated